# Extract data from ERP to SQl database in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to extract data from Sage ERP (which will be updated automatically every month) and transfer it to the SQL database using azure data factory. But I don't know much about ERP. Also, I can't share any data. Anyone can please help me or give me an idea about it?

I can't try to do anything because now I don't have any credentials If I send my client documentation for this process. They will ask me to work on their system

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out of box ADF connector available to copy data from Sage ERP.

As an alternative, you may explore [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity) or Azure function activity in ADF. To move data to/from a data store that the service does not support, or to transform/process data in a way that isn't supported by the service, you can create a Custom activity with your own data movement or transformation logic and use the activity in a pipeline. The custom activity runs your customized code logic on an Azure Batch pool of virtual machines.

I would also recommend you to please submit a feature request for the same in IDEAS forum: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c